# Hiding Prev/Next buttons on first/last pages

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, I've done some searching but I can't quite find anything that works for my code, so I thought I'd give it a shot.

I'm building a slideshow-type navigation for my page (mostly as a learning exercise) and I want to be able to hide the "Prev" button on the first slide and the "next" button on the last slide, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide active-slide first">
    <div class="content">
        <p>First Slide</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
        <p>second slide</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide last">
    <div class="content">
        <p>third slide</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-nav">
    <div class="prev">
        prev
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        next
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
var main = function() { 
    if($('.active-slide').hasClass('first')) {
       $('.prev').hide(); 
} else if ($('.active-slide').hasClass('last')) {
           $('.next').hide();
} else {
    $('.prev').show();
    $('.next').show();
}
$('.next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slide');

//if nextslide is last slide, go back to the first
        if(nextSlide.length===0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        } 

        currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(1100).addClass('active-slide');

    });

//prev slide function
    $('.prev').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev('.slide');

        if(prevSlide.length===0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    });

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/794f4yvw/5/) with the same thing.
I feel like there is a better way to do it than using "first" and "last" classes for my first and last slides, but I thought this might be easier. I'm open to all suggestions though!

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with using and extra `first` and `last` class. You could, alternatively, get a list of all `.slide` (get it once and cache it unless the list of slide is supposed to be dynamic) and compare the current slide to the first and last item in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see the corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/794f4yvw/12/
I've added prev/next check as a separate function and call every time the slide is switched:

```
function checkNavigation() {

    if ($('.active-slide').hasClass('first')) {
        $('.prev').hide();
        $('.next').show();
    } else if ($('.active-slide').hasClass('last')) {
        $('.next').hide();
        $('.prev').show();
    } else {
        $('.prev').show();
        $('.next').show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Only potential problem is if you have only one slide, presumably with both `first` and `last`.

Comment: You can also delete unnecessary `if (nextSlide.length === 0)` and `if (prevSlide.length === 0)`

Comment: agree, then the whole function should be rewritten to handle this and for example starting from custom slide (!=first)