# How to remove previous button from first page and next button from last page?

Tags: javascript, html

So I need help with removing the previous button from the first page, and the next button from the last page.

This is my Script. The whole thing is 11 pages, and all of them are `.png` images with the buttons next and previous.

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="myImg" src="step1.png">
  <button class="btn1" onclick='next()'>Напред</button>
  <button class="btn4" onclick='prev()'>Назад</button>
</div>

<script>
var curPage=1;
function next(){
    curPage++;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}

function prev(){
  curPage--;
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}


</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding Prev/Next buttons on first/last pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750067/hiding-prev-next-buttons-on-first-last-pages)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
  <img id="myImg" src="step1.png">
  <button class="btn1" onclick='next()'>Напред</button>
  <button class="btn4" onclick='prev()'>Назад</button>
</div>

<script>
var curPage=1;
function checkButtons(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn1").style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn4").style.display = 'inline-block';
  if(curPage === 1)
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn1").style.display = 'none';
  if(curPage === 11)
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn4").style.display = 'none';
}
function next(){
    curPage++;
    checkButtons();
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}

function prev(){
  curPage--;
  checkButtons();
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "step"+curPage+".png";
}


</script>
```